# DirectX SDK June 2010 issue

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, directx

I'm trying to run the sample code from the book [Physics for Game Programmers](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596000066.do). I have installed the DirectX SDK June 2010 but get the following errors.

```
Cannot open include file: 'd3drmwin.h'
Cannot open include file: <d3drm.h>
Cannot open include file: <d3dtypes.h>
```

I believe I have added all necessary include and library paths and Additional Dependencies (D3D10.lib & D3DX10.lib) as I can access the header files d3d10.h and d3d9.h without any issues.

Any ideas how to get their code running? Is the code possibly referencing a old version of DirectX?

Edit: I have installed the SDK and Set up the following:

Project->Properties->VC++ Directories->Include Directories and added

```
C:\Program Files %28x86%29\Microsoft DirectX SDK %28June 2010%29\Include;
```

Project->Properties->VC++ Directories->Library Directories and added

```
C:\Program Files %28x86%29\Microsoft DirectX SDK %28June 2010%29\Lib\x86;
```

Project->Properties->Linker->Input and added

```
D3D10.lib;D3DX10.lib
```

Edit

Ok, I have figured out those header files belong to DirectX 8. So the latest SDK doesn't support them. Now i just have to figure out where to download the DirectX 8 SDK. Any ideas where to find it?

Comment: The problem is that the compiler can't find the header files you've listed, so you haven't added the proper include paths. It has nothing to do with the Direct X version; the errors specifically say they can't open the header files.

Comment: I have added the set up steps I have done to the question. Any change you could have a look and tell me what I'm missing? Cheers

Comment: can you upload the files from `lib` and `include` folders? I am unable to install this sdk

Answer (score 2):

Change the paths to the folders to use double quotes properly, as in

```
"C:\Program Files x86\Microsoft DirectX SDK June 2010\Include;"
```

Windows is not a web browser; it's an operating system. It doesn't understand URL encoding as far as directory locations go. (I don't have the book, but it's probably a typo there.)

Comment: That's how the "Browse for Directories" added them. ie. Visual Studio added them like that. I changed it to use quotes but still no luck

Comment: So it looks like those header files belong to DirectX 8. Any ideas where I can download that from? Its not available on MSDN site.

Comment: I have them in a current installation of C++Builder (an Embarcadero C++ IDE and compiler), so they should still be there in a current version of the DX SDK. However, they're also there in a 2007 version of the same product, so it looks like you've missed a download. I'd suggest you just get the latest version of the DX SDK; you'll probably have to make some changes to get them to work, but you'll eventually need to do that anyway to work with current versions.

Comment: Thanks Ken. I will have a look.